# Apache Cordova media capture plugin doesn't show video record count down time

Tags: java, android, cordova, video-capture, cordova-3

I am using Cordova media capture plugin to record video. I used the maximum record time as 15 seconds like:

```
//limit capture operation to 1 media files, no longer than 15 seconds each
var options = { limit: 1, duration: 15 };   
navigator.device.capture.capturevideo(capturevideo_success, captureError, options);
```

I am able to record 15 seconds video as it stops once 15 seconds is completed, however it doesn't show in progress duration. It just shows like

```
00:...
```

Can I display in progress duration or count down time using this plugin. Kindly help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The recording is being performed by the device camera application, the Cordova API passes control over to that app to do the recording and there is nothing exposed that would allow you to show a countdown or anything like that.

Comment: however when I am not specifying the duration, then it shows recording time. So I assume there must be something to handle this.